# Opening CefSharp Window a second time crashes the application

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Now I don't have much code as such to show (I'm not sure what or where the issue is, which is why i'm posting)

I'm using cefSharp on a browser window (which works fine the first time it's loaded) I prompt the user to close the browser window when finished, on doing so I properly dispose & shut down cefsharp as shown in their github docs.

```
    panelBrowserMain.Controls.Remove(browser);
    browser.Dispose();
    Cef.Shutdown();
```

The problem is, when I go to open the browser window form again to use, it immediately closes with the error:

```
has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

And shows me absolutely no information on what went wrong so I can fix it, i'm in the dark, has anyone come accross this or is there a way i can see what actually happened on the crash, it's like working in the dark with no concrete information.

Comment: Well, you disposed the browser (and shutdown CEF). You can't use the same browser anymore after that. It's worth doing `browser.Dispose(); browser = null;` so you get an early null reference exception.

Comment: Thank you AKX, i don't think i needed to ```Cef.Shutdown()``` at all! i tweaked a few things and now it's working, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Once you call Cef.Shutdown you can no longer create new ChromiumWebBrowser instances. It's not possible to call Cef.Initialize a second time,  this is a chromium limitation. A more meaningful exception should be shown starting in version 92, which version are you using? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/15f70114405a01708d7d986b55c8ec0444b39785#diff-5e5fb4f05a0c18b73e52435847e8825b12b2e9946c13831b0ac8b6c41461589b